# Points based curve transformation. Bezier curve transform in Android

Tags: java, android, bezier, curve, smoothing

I have a list of points that represents a curve which I draw on a canvas using a Path object.

```
path.moveTo(x, y);
for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
    path.lineTo(points.get(i).x, points.get(i).y);
}
canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
```

What I want to achieve is ability to set control points that user can touch and move and based on that movement my points will get transformed. Same thing that photoshop does with `Pen Tool` see image:
[image]

**Note: android Path is only used for drawing, I don't need to modify Path I need to modify coordinates. so code above can be replaced with**

```
canvas.drawLine();
```

It nothing has to do with Path object.

Comment: read `android.graphics.Path` docs, they explain how to deal with bezier curves

Comment: I've read that, it only modifies path thru matrices, and as you can see from the picture what I need is completely different and cannot be achieved with matrix transform

Comment: you need to build your path from the scratch (`reset` method followed by `moveTo` and couple of `cubicTo` methods) whenever any control point changes

Comment: please read question again, what you are suggesting cannot solve the problem I have. It is about points modification so that path can be transformed in any place, it is not about scale/shift/skew

Comment: I am not asking about how to redraw / re-draw the path I am asking for algorithm that modifies points so that path behaves like a string in real life when you drag it it changes the shape. If you still don't get the question try to open photoshop and see how pen tool works

Comment: code is in question, but please forget about Path object it is not about path, it is about coordinates. so question is about modifying coordinates and path is only used to draw coordinates on canvas, it is not even about android, question is general about how to modify points so that they follow your finger movement in non linear way.

Comment: oh man please. I don't need path I need coordinates/pixels. it is all about coordinates and pixels. I need general java algorithm and there is no Path object at all. I don't know how else to explain. no path no canvas just pixel manipulation.

Comment: yes I need to calculate every x, y since end result need to be list of coordinates. and yes it needs to be a math formula. have you seen how pen tool works in Photoshop ? https://youtu.be/dSdov7nVYdo?t=2m30s see how he clicks and moves pointer, note that's only one point and there can be many

Comment: can you change it that so there are 5 control points ?

Comment: it was a rhetorical question if you didn't notice

Comment: what you proposed is not a solution. that's what I am trying to explain. path.cubicTo has only two control points and if you try to chain you will endup with sharp ends. try to read understand problem before offering solutions that first google search returns.

Comment: oh my gash. I tired explaining that path approach won't work. If you have a working answer that modifies pixels post it otherwise forget it please.

Comment: of course I do, you have 4 control points and one anchor, if you change anchor point you will see sharp edge, to avoid sharp edge you will need to change control points which will change cultivation that is not expected. and all in all it is not the solution I need. because as I said forget about path I need coordinate manipulation. I value your effort so you can post your code as answer I will upwote it.

Comment: yeah, I've read and if you didn't notice I will say it again "to avoid sharp edge you will need to change control points which will change curvature that is not expected." meaning new shape is not natural looking. I don't want to go with Path for main reason that it gives limited features to modify curve. and it brings additional dependency.

Comment: ok have an answer - post it. this conversation became too long for comments. Good article though. thanks.

Answer (score 5):

this is the simple view that uses one "anchor" point and two control points, if you need more anchors, add another `cubicTo` to your path:

```
class V extends View {
    static final float RADIUS = 32;
    Path path = new Path();
    Paint pathPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    Paint controlPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    PointF ctrl1 = new PointF();
    PointF ctrl2 = new PointF();
    PointF ctrl3 = new PointF();
    PointF ctrl4 = new PointF();
    PointF anchor = new PointF();
    GestureDetector detector;
    Layout layout;

    public V(Context context) {
        super(context);
        pathPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        pathPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        pathPaint.setStrokeWidth(16);
        controlPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        controlPaint.setAlpha(128);
        detector = new GestureDetector(context, listener);
    }

    GestureDetector.OnGestureListener listener = new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        PointF target;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            PointF[] targets = { ctrl2, ctrl3, anchor };
            for (PointF t : targets) {
                if (Math.hypot(t.x - e.getX(), t.y - e.getY()) < RADIUS) {
                    target = t;
                    return true;
                }
            }
            target = null;
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
            if (target == null) return false;

            target.offset(-distanceX, -distanceY);
            if (target == ctrl2 || target == ctrl3) {
                PointF otherControl = target == ctrl2 ? ctrl3 : ctrl2;
                // anchor just between points
                double a = Math.atan2(anchor.y - target.y, anchor.x - target.x);
                double r = Math.hypot(otherControl.x - anchor.x, otherControl.y - anchor.y);
                otherControl.set((float) (anchor.x + r * Math.cos(a)), (float) (anchor.y + r * Math.sin(a)));

                // anchor always in the center
//                otherControl.set(2 * anchor.x - target.x, 2 * anchor.y - target.y);
            } else {
                ctrl2.offset(-distanceX, -distanceY);
                ctrl3.offset(-distanceX, -distanceY);
            }
            rebuildPath();
            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        ctrl1.set(w * 0.0f, h * 1.0f);
        ctrl2.set(w * 0.1f, h * 0.5f);
        ctrl3.set(w * 0.9f, h * 0.5f);
        ctrl4.set(w * 1.0f, h * 1.0f);
        anchor.set(w * 0.5f, h * 0.5f);
        rebuildPath();
        CharSequence src = "you can drag any green circle: the both control points or the anchor point\n\n" +
                "notice that the control points can be adjusted individually - the only constraint for a smooth line is that the anchor point is between them (but not necessarily in the exact center)";
        TextPaint tp = new TextPaint();
        tp.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        tp.setTextSize(32);
        layout = new StaticLayout(src, tp, w - 64, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1, 0, true);
    }

    private void rebuildPath() {
        path.reset();
        path.moveTo(ctrl1.x, ctrl1.y);
        path.cubicTo(ctrl1.x, ctrl1.y, ctrl2.x, ctrl2.y, anchor.x, anchor.y);
        path.cubicTo(ctrl3.x, ctrl3.y, ctrl4.x, ctrl4.y, ctrl4.x, ctrl4.y);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        detector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(32, 32);
        layout.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
        canvas.drawPath(path, pathPaint);
        controlPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        canvas.drawCircle(anchor.x, anchor.y, RADIUS, controlPaint);
        canvas.drawCircle(ctrl2.x, ctrl2.y, RADIUS, controlPaint);
        canvas.drawCircle(ctrl3.x, ctrl3.y, RADIUS, controlPaint);
        controlPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        canvas.drawLine(ctrl2.x, ctrl2.y, ctrl3.x, ctrl3.y, controlPaint);
    }
}
```

Comment: nice work man this is exactly what I have been looking for. Thanks